# setRootController error using react-native-navigation in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I keep running into `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCCManager.setRootController')` when trying to use react-native-navigation.

I tried to follow suit with https://github.com/junedomingo/movieapp but hit this when it tries to load the project in the Expo app.

I've modified my App.js generated by Expo to look like this:

```js
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'

Navigation.registerComponent('screens.HomeScreen', () => HomeScreen)

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.startApp()
  }
  startApp() {
    Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
      tabs: [
        {
        label: 'One',
        screen: 'screens.HomeScreen',
        title: 'Screen One'
        },
      ]
    })
  }
}

const app = new App()
```

That's a bit boiled down, but I think those are the essential bits.  I feel like I'm not handing things off from rnn to Expo the way Expo is expecting.

Any idea how to get rnn running in Expo?  If there's an example repo I can play with, that would be great.  I'm sure I can get rnn working outside Expo, so vanilla rnn examples probably won't help much.

Comment: I believe  react-native-navigation is not supported by expo. It has native dependencies.

Comment: I think you meant to use react-navigation.

Comment: In fact like @EdgarAroutiounian said in order to use react-native-navigation by Wix, you need to modify either the android and iOS native code. Edgar do you know if there's a way to generate such folders within expo without losing the advantages?

Comment: @JuanCarlosAlpizarChinchilla Look at ExpoKit: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/expokit.html

Comment: @bennygenel I believe you're right.  If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because react-native-navigation has native dependencies and need you to add custom native code you can not use it with Expo out of the package.

One option is to [detach](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html) your project and use the package like that. This has a side effect of loosing some expo properties.

Another option is *(if you are not too deep in the project)* creating a new app with [react-native-cli](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/understanding-cli.html) and moving your code to that project. This has side effect of not being able to use expo api.

Third option is to use a navigation package that doesn't depend on native code. Some of the most popular options are [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) and [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux).